# return responseText from jQuery.get()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, get

I tried to do something like this :

```
var msg = $.get("my_script.php");
```

I thought msg would be set to the text returned by my_script.php,i.e. the responseText of the jqXHR object.
It apparently doesn't work like that as msg is always set to "[object XMLHttpRequest]"

Is there a quick 1 line way to do what I want?

Thanks.

Comment: That will certainly work, but a synchronous call will obviously block code execution. If you need to work with the value returned in msg it's usually (although not always) better to work with it inside the callback itslef, as suggested by @Vitor-Mello. Guess it depends if you can move your code inside the callback function.

Comment: @katsuo11 This is the best solution

Comment: Could you add your own solution as an answer? It is the only one that works for me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After some testing, I ended up finding a solution.

I need the call to be synchronous, $.get shorthand function is always asynchonous, so I will need to use $.ajax, like this:

```
var msg = $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "my_script.php", async: false}).responseText;
```

I don't think there is a better way to do this, thanks for your answers.

Comment: With this line, I got the following in my browser console: jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Answer (score 7):

You can always use:

```
var msg;
$.get("my_script.php", function(text) {
  msg = text;
});
```

If for some reason the response is text, the remote script might be changing the content-type to something like JSON, and thus jQuery tries to parse the string before outputting to you.

Comment: I don't want an alert box with the text response, I want the msg var actally set to the text response

Comment: Hey, there is 2 problems with your updated code, msg cannot be accessed inside the callback function without declaring it globally. But even if you do so, the call being asynchronous, you will mostly try to use msg before the call to my_script.php is done. I updated my question to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The return value is simply the jqXHR object used for the ajax request. To get the response data you need to register a callback.

```
$.get("my_script.php", function(data) {
  var msg = data;
  alert(msg);
});
```

Comment: why it just cna't be alert(data); ? why need new variable? to waste ram?

Answer (score 1):

The response text is available in the success callback; do what you need to do with it there.

Comment: Problem is, in the success callback, I'm out of scope from where I call $.get(), e.g. `var msg = '';$.get("my_script.php", function(data){msg = data.responseText});`, here in the callback function, msg cannot be accessed.

Comment: Call a function that sets the global value, or use a closure to keep the value of an object or module.

Comment: @DaveNewton can you give an example where it sets a global value?

Comment: @Chud37 Two other answers show setting a variable in the success callback. To set a global don't define what you're setting with a `var`. This is risky, and very dependent on the luck of timing unless you're doing it async, which defeats the purpose.