# Variables set after Jquery GET response

Tags: php, jquery, get, highcharts

I'm building a data set using javascript and jquery 'get' methods.  I want to set 2  arrays to the responses from a couple of jquery gets.  But the data is 'undefined' where I think it was set already. I need the data variables, as I use them further down in my code.  Here is the setup:

```
var data1, data2;

$.get('metabolitemetrics2.php', function(data) { data1 = data });
$.get('metrics.php?view='+duration, function(data){ data2 = data});

alert(data1);
alert(data2);
```

EDIT: found the answer! I needed to change the call from a jquery get, into an ajax get. IE;
[return responseText from jQuery.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598821/return-responsetext-from-jquery-get)
Thanks!

Comment: Asynchronous nature of javascript: `$.get('metabolitemetrics2.php', function(data) { data1 = data; alert(data1); });` should work

Comment: The magic word is asynchronous !

Comment: when I alert the data, it does work-- but I need the data outside the call.  I don't know how to expand the scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is due to the scope. 
$.get()'s data scope is limited to its braces.
There is a trick that get the data and set it in some hidden div or span, and get it after the get calls.