# Not getting html response from servelet through ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, ckeditor

I have made ckeditor plugin to convert doc file to html, the file is uploaded via servlet witha ajax and converted to html. But I am not getting desired html response from servlet. I am getting the same jsp page in result.

Here is Servlet code.

```
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
    // HttpSession
            response.setContentType("text/html");                                                                           // session;
            if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN,
                        "only multipart requests are allowed");
                return;
            }
            WebappContext webappContext = WebappContext.get(getServletContext());
            ServletFileUpload fileUpload = webappContext.getFileUpload();

            OfficeDocumentConverter converter = webappContext
                    .getDocumentConverter();
            String outputExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(request
                    .getRequestURI());
            FileItem uploadedFile;
            try {
                uploadedFile = getUploadedFile(fileUpload, request);
                // FileHandler.checkForValidExtn(uploadedFile);
            } catch (FileUploadException fileUploadException) {
                throw new ServletException(fileUploadException);
            }
            if (uploadedFile == null) {
                throw new NullPointerException("uploaded file is null");
            }
            String inputExtension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(uploadedFile
                    .getName());
            String baseName = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(uploadedFile.getName());
            // File fileFolder=new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
            // +"images");
            // fileFolder.mkdir();
            // File inputFile=new File(fileFolder+"\\"+ baseName + "." +
            // inputExtension);
            File inputFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
                    + baseName + "." + inputExtension);

            writeUploadedFile(uploadedFile, inputFile);
            File outputFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
                    + baseName + "." + "html");
            // File outputFile=new File(fileFolder+"\\"+ baseName + "." + "html");
            // outputFile.mkdirs();
            System.out.println("input file path:" + inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("outPut file path:" + outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
            try {
                // DocumentFormat outputFormat = converter.getFormatRegistry()
                // .getFormatByExtension(outputExtension);
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                converter.convert(inputFile, outputFile);
                long conversionTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                logger.info(String.format(
                        "successful conversion: %s [%db] to %s in %dms",
                        inputExtension, inputFile.length(), outputExtension,
                        conversionTime));
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                logger.severe(String.format(
                        "failed conversion: %s [%db] to %s; %s; input file: %s",
                        inputExtension, inputFile.length(), outputExtension,
                        exception, inputFile.getName()));
                throw new ServletException("conversion failed", exception);
            } finally {
                 inputFile.delete();
            }
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<b>File Sent to server</b>");
            out.close();
}
```

Here is code javascript code for sendi file to server.

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'uploadDoc', function( editor ) 
{    var dialougeDefination = 
        {   title:          editor.lang.uploadDoc.labelName,
            resizable:      CKEDITOR.DIALOG_RESIZE_BOTH,
            minWidth:       250,
            minHeight:      50,
            onOk:       function()
                {   if(document.getElementById("flFileBrowser").value == "")
                        {   alert("No file selected");
                            //return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $.ajax({

                                beforeSend: function(){
                                    {    $("#frmFileUpload").ajaxSubmit();
                                    $.blockUI();
                                    }
                                },

                                success: function(result)
                                {   alert(result);

                                    $.unblockUI();
                                }

                            });
```

Comment: so there is plenty of code there to debug. Do you know if the problem is on the server or the client.

Comment: Looks like the browser you're using to test this doesn't support file upload by ajax (more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2320069/1065197). It would be better using/adapting a plugin for this like [blueimp jquery file upload plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/166221/1065197

Comment: The file is getting uploaded and getting converted to html.
The problem is that servlet is not sending response in result string.
I am getting response as the same jsp page where I placed, ckeditor.

Comment: is ckeditor in an iframe?

Comment: No it is attached to textarea, there's no iframe

Comment: ah so you want result.responseText

Comment: yes I want the response html string from Servelet

Comment: Yes, so alert(result.responseText)

Answer (score 0):

The response is actually in the responseText field, so your code should be

```
alert(result.responseText);
```

Comment: i have written alert(result); result is coming as pure string there are no properties associated.

Comment: success: function(result) - this result has a responseText field.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598821/return-responsetext-from-jquery-get

Comment: result.responseText is undefine, might be
 beforeSend: function(){
                                    {    $("#frmFileUpload").ajaxSubmit();
                                    $.blockUI();
                                    }
                                }
is creating an issue. in beforeSend callback i am uploading file