# How can I store my ajax data in a global variable?

Tags: jquery, json

```
$(document).ready (function() {

    var shuffle = function(a) {
    for(var j, x, i = a.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = a[--i],                    a[i] = a[j], a[j] = x);
    return a;
};
```

I want the local variable 'fullName' to have the ajax data and I want to use that for the global variable 'fullName'

```
var fullName;
var randomShuff = shuffle(fullName); 
var i = 0

$(".runRandomPart").on('click', function() {
     if(i == randomShuff.length) 
          i = 0;
     return $('.main').html(randomShuff[i++]);
});
```

Here's the ajax data I'm trying to store in a global variable.  Maybe it's a scope issue.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/students",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(results){

        var arr = results;

        for (d=0; d<arr.length; d++) {  
            fullName = arr[d].last_name + ", " + arr[d].first_name; 
        }
    }
});
```

I tried putting all the functionality in the ajax function but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I found this. I think that this will solve your requirements:
[return responseText from jQuery.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598821/return-responsetext-from-jquery-get)

Comment: You're right, I left it out by accident.  I have corrected that in the example but I still can't get data from 'fullName' local to 'fullName' global

Comment: ok, I think that you need a return statement, could you try something like this? :

`fullName = $.ajax({
    url: "/api/students",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(results){

        var arr = results;
        var fullName = '';
        for (d=0; d<arr.length; d++) {  
            fullName = arr[d].last_name + ", " + arr[d].first_name; 
        }
         return fullName;
    }
});`

I hope this could be helpful  :)

Comment: I missed a var before first fullName ( ... like this? : **var** fullName ...)

Answer (score 0):

Try using window.fullName instead.